# Why my for loop give me always the same result?

Tags: react-native, for-loop

I try to make an exercise where you have to calculate multiplication here is the code to create the questions.

```
   const [questionsArray,setQuestionsArray] = useState([]);
   const [multiplyArray, setMultiplyArray] = useState([35]);
   const [multBy, setMultBy] = useState(5);

   function createQuestionsArray() {
     for (var m = 0; m < multiplyArray.length; m++) {
       for (var b = 1; b < multBy+1; b++) {
         var question = multiplyArray[m]+'x'+b;
         setQuestionsArray((prev) => [...prev, question]);
       }
     }
   }
```

So what I want at the end is questionArray = [35x1,35x2,35x3,35x4,35x5] but I have questionArray = [35x5,35x5,35x5,35x5,35x5].
What is the problem? please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I did same thing but with "while" and it worked, so I still don't understand the problem but I can continue my app ^^

Should I delete my question?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, where is `prev` coming from in `setQuestionsArray(...)`?

Why not use:

```
        setQuestionsArray( [...questionsArray, question] );
```

Edit:
Weird that the while loop fixed it...
Converting this to vanilla javascript works:

```
const multiplyArray = [35];
const multBy = 5;
let questionsArray = [];

function createQuestionsArray() {
 for (var m = 0; m < multiplyArray.length; m++) {
   for (var b = 1; b < multBy+1; b++) {
     var question = multiplyArray[m]+'x'+b;
     questionsArray = [...questionsArray, question];
   }
 }
}

createQuestionsArray();

// questionsArray = [ '35x1', '35x2', '35x3', '35x4', '35x5' ]
```

Comment: Because It work like this in other functions I did also I tried like you said but give the same result :/

Comment: Is there any other code that wasn't included here, or are you just calling createQuestionsArray() with the above variables? 
I haven't used react, but should [questionsArray, setQuestionsArray] be a constant, looks like it gets reassigned each loop? Again not sure about react, but looks like the setter is pointing to a new array.